# how to join the result of ls command into a string using comma

Tags: linux, shell

I 'm using linux shell.

I want to join the `ls .` result into a string.

for example:

```
a=`ls .`
echo $a
```

then the $a will be "file1 file2 file3"

but I want it to be "file1,file2,file3"

hot to realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ ls -xm
$ # or
$ echo `ls .`|sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Comment: oh, thank you all the same:-)  although I found the solution by myself:-)

Comment: `ls -xm` is a really nice way to get a one-line comment separated output.

However, you need to set the outpu width with `-w` / `--width` to ensure lines don't wrap for consistent output.

Some `ls` implementations seem to accept `--width=0` to mean no width limit, but others don't, and instead you can set `--width=10000` or some other arbitrarily large number.